# The backing-file for the real-time session "WSSUSAGESESSION15" has reached its maximum size

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Our SharePoint 2013 server is logging the following error message every 5min which is really filling up our Eventlogs. The question is now how we can close/stop this?

```
Log Name:      Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-EventTracing/Admin
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-EventTracing
Date:          2017-08-22 10:19:30
Event ID:      1
Task Category: Logging
Level:         Warning
Keywords:      Session
User:          SYSTEM
Computer:      sharepoint01.int.contoso.com
Description:
The backing-file for the real-time session "WSSUSAGESESSION15" has reached its maximum size. As a result, new events will not be logged to this session until space becomes available. This error is often caused by starting a trace session in real-time mode without having any real-time consumers.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-EventTracing" Guid="{B675EC37-BDB6-4648-BC92-F3FDC74D3CA2}" />
    <EventID>1</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>3</Level>
    <Task>1</Task>
    <Opcode>10</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8000000000000010</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2017-08-22T08:19:30.134550800Z" />
    <EventRecordID>70919</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="2552" />
    <Channel>Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-EventTracing/Admin</Channel>
    <Computer>sharepoint01.int.contoso.com</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="SessionName">WSSUSAGESESSION15</Data>
    <Data Name="ErrorCode">3221225864</Data>
    <Data Name="LoggingMode">25166208</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```